# Can docker overlay networks bind to a single specific parent network interface?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I am creating `docker service`'s with docker swarm.  I want each of my docker services to have their own specific IP addresses on each swarm node.   So my instances have multiple network interfaces (eth1, eth2 and eth3) each with their own different IP addresses.  I want to be able to create docker overlay networks that are connected to a **single** parent network interface on each node, so that each docker service will have its own IP address on each node.

Here is my attempt at creating such a network and a service to go with it:

```
docker network create -d overlay \
-o parent=eth2 \
nginx1-net

docker service create \
--mode global \
--name nginx1 \
-p 30000:80/tcp \
--network nginx1-net \
nginx
```

The issue is that this overlay network `nginx1-net` will only appear on the management node I create it on and will not appear on any other nodes. (I suspect that this is because the service will then attach itself to docker0 and eth0 by default)

This then causes the situation where I can access this service from any IP address on any interface (eth1, eth2 and eth3) and not just the eth2 interface I define.

How to I bind my overlay network and docker service to a single network interface?

**Note:** My overall goal is to create docker services, where each container will have an external routable IP address.

Comment: http://collabnix.com/archives/1445 is a good read on that topic (not a definitive answer though)